# Understanding the DAX CALCULATE function

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am working on a model in Power BI that has two datasets:

`Set_1` (just a list of each group name)

```
Group:
1
2
3
```

and `Set_2`, a bunch of values per group in a different dataset:

```
Group:    Value:
1         10
1         20
1         -7
2         100
2         -25
3         45
3         15
1         3
```

The tables are related by group. I want to create a measure on `Set_1` that shows the sum of the values by group in `Set_2`. I can do so with the following DAX formula:

```
GroupSum = CALCULATE(SUMX(Set_2, Set_2[Value]))
```

looks like this

```
Group:    GroupSum:
1         26
2         75
3         60
```

But I don't understand why the `CALCULATE` function, which doesn't take any filter contexts as parameters works the way it does in this instance. Without the `CALCULATE` function,

```
GroupSum = SUMX(Set_2, Set_2[Value])
```

looks like this:

```
Group:    GroupSum:
1         161
2         161
3         161
```

Which makes sense. I just need help understanding how the Calculate function works, specifically when it isn't passed any filter parameters.

EDIT: The answer lies in the concept of "context transition" as pointed out below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `CALCULATE` function makes the DAX perform a **context transition**.

> CALCULATE transforms all existing row contexts into an equivalent filter context before applying its filter arguments to the original filter context.

For more detail on this, check out the site I quoted above:
[Understanding Context Transition](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-context-transition/).

---

In your example, the value in the `Group` column of each row acts as a filter when you use `CALCULATE` as if you had written something like `CALCULATE(SUM(Set_2[Value]), Set_2[Group] = 1)`. Even though it doesn't have an explicit filter, the row context acts as a filter.